In google forms API, is there a limited number of items allowed per batch update?
I'm using google forms to display pictures I have available for sale. What I'm doing is sending the pictures using the google forms API batchUpdate method:
https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/batchUpdate
The problem is when I reach 40 pictures I get a 500 response saying it could not load the picture, it was working fine with less than 40 images. Does anybody know if there is a way to fix this? Or what could be causing this issue.
I also tried using make.com to update the images and I still get the same error when reaching 40 images.

Here's the Usage limits for the Google Forms API. I don't know, haven't read but it sounds as though you're hitting quota. The documentation explains quotas and explains how to increase those that can be.

The error 500 might be caused by reasons unrelated to your code. You might try again later, or instead of using a single batchUpdate, use multiple, let's say, one for each subset of 40 images.
From the question

I'm using google forms to display pictures I have available for sale.

This looks like an edge case. Google Forms is not intended for that (showing a large set of pictures). Regarding limits, Google Forms is only suitable for handling a few items; Google has not disclosed the item's limits, meaning that it could be changed at any time without announcing the change.
It seems like you would benefit from using Google Photos to create a photo album, Google Slides to create a slide deck/presentation, or Google Apps Script to create a web app; these could be embedded on a site using Google Sites and a Google Form might be embedded on the same page.
Another option is that you use more than one form, let say a form for each subset of 40 images.
Related

Google Form Limit to Number of Dropdown Options

